# Heat transfer and steady state

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a metal rod between two bodies of different temperature.How do you explain the occurrence of steady-state when heat Is transferring by conduction through the rod. I mean why should there exist a point called steady-state in the first place, meaning why the temperature of the rod at a point become static in steady state?

Comment: You first.  Why would you think there wouldn't be a steady state?

Comment: @ChetMiller I’m not sure about such occurrence and unable to judge the outcome of conduction(I.e. steady state)....ok let me do it...first due to the difference in the temperature, the heat starts flowing through the rod.the temperature of initial parts of rod are more than the  far ones..so the heat flow continues...considering an arbitrary segment...the heat flows from the higher temperature part towards the segment...the segment could absorb the heat and increase its temperature...and then the part adjacent to the chosen segment experiences heat flow...such that

Comment: @ChetMiller continuation to my previous reply.......remove such that.........the so continues across the rod then we might think there may exist thermal equilibrium between the adjacent parts of rod....ahh..I’m stuck here ....guide me from here...if this is correct.

Comment: Yes.  This is an accurate description of what happens.  So, as time progresses, the temperature profile evolves until there is a linear profile between the hot end and the cold end.  At this point, the heat flowing into any segment of the rod equals the heat flowing out, so there is no longer a tendency for its temperature to change.

Comment: Can the temperatures be equal throughout the rod then...!?

Comment: No.  I said that the temperature profile at steady state will be spatially linear, varying from the low temperature at one end to the high temperature at the other end.  But it will not be varying with time at final steady state.

Comment: @ChetMiller yeah I totally understand what u have said...and steady state is achieved now...fine but why there exists a temperature difference across the rod...(I mean why the temperature profile at steady state is linear.)(meaning can it be constant also??...).....my final question is that why not thermal equilibrium in the rod...between the parts.

Comment: I mean..in steady state the temperature of the parts of the rod are differed right....I am wondering why....

Comment: They are different because heat flows from hot to cold.  If it's all at one temperature, which end do you fail to match, the high end temperature of the low end temperature?

Comment: @ChetMiller are you talking about the case where the ends of rod are attached to the temperatures which are fixed...(maintained constant).....in that case you might be right! I was suddenly thinking of three bodies 2ends and 1 rod...in this case I hope there exists thermal equilibrium right?.?

Comment: Yes.  The three bodies will equilibrate at a final temperature, provided they are insulated from everything else.

Comment: Now after concluding steady state is achieved can you explain how it’s achieved still scratching my head regarding...it....like taking the temperatures of the ends and rod,can you explain kinda in detail...that would be great,please..add an answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93258/discussion-between-pss-1-and-chet-miller).

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very crude description of what is happening, but it captures the basic physical mechanisms in play.  Suppose that the entire rod is initially at the temperature $T_c$ and at time t = 0, the left end of the rod x = 0 is suddenly raised to temperature $T_h$  (and held at that temperature forever afterward) while the right end of the rod x = L continues to be held at temperature $T_c$.

Heat will begin to propagate into the rod (by conduction) from the left end, and, as time progresses, the "effective" depth of propagation $\delta(t)$ of the disturbed region will grow with time, until the depth of penetration encompasses the entire rod.  A crude approximation to the temperature profile within the rod at any time can be taken as:  $$T=T_h-(T_h-T_c)\frac{x}{\delta(t)}\tag{for x < delta}$$and$$T=T_c\tag{for x > delta}$$The total amount of heat that has entered the rod at any time is equal to $$\int_0^L{\rho C A(T-T_c)}dx$$ where $\rho$ is the rod density, C is the specific heat capacity, and A is the cross sectional area. For the assumed temperature profile, this becomes $$\rho C A (T_h-T_c)\frac{\delta(t)}{2}$$Also, from the assumed temperature profile, the rate of heat flow into the rod at the left end is $$kA\frac{(T_h-T_c)}{\delta(t)}$$ and the rate of heat flow out of the rod at the right end is zero, where k is the thermal conductivity.  So, a time-dependent heat balance on the rod gives:$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\rho C A (T_h-T_c)\frac{\delta(t)}{2}\right)=kA\frac{(T_h-T_c)}{\delta(t)}$$or, equivalently,$$\delta\frac{d\delta}{dt}=2\frac{k}{\rho C}$$The solution to this differential equation is $$\delta(t)=2\sqrt{\frac{k}{\rho C}t}$$So this equation tells us the effective distance of penetration of the thermal boundary layer into the rod as a function of time.  Steady state is approximately attained when $\delta = L$, or, equivalently, when $$t=\frac{\rho C}{k}\frac{L^2}{4}$$
As I said, this is a very crude approximation to the solution to the transient heat conduction equation, but it includes all the important physical mechanisms.

Comment: Sir whats the Intuition behind the first approximation to the temperature profile?

Comment: The intuition is based on the expectation that the temperature profile will propagate in wave-like fashion across the rod.  Of course, being familiar with  the exact boundary layer solution for heat penetration into a semi-infinite slab helped too; at short times, the transient solution for a finite rod would be expected to closely match that solution.  The equations and approximate approach I used in the above answer is referred to in the literature as the "energy integral method."

Comment: I might also mention that the exact solution to this transient heat transfer problem for a rod is continuous and has a continuous first spatial derivative.  However, the exact temperature profile and the present approximation share the same overall characteristics.

Comment: Can you make it high school level.